# Undergraduate resources for gates in quantum computing?

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I am wondering if anyone knows of any resources that take an elementary, undergraduate-friendly approach to the theorem, due (I believe) to Deutsch and Divincenzo, that two-qubit gates are universal for quantum computation. In other words, any unitary transformation $U \in SU(2^n)$ can be approximated arbitrarily well by a finite sequence $U = U_1 \cdots U_r$ of unitary transformations, each with the property $U_i = I_s \otimes U'_i \otimes I_{n-s-2}$, where $U'_i \in SU(2)$. I am aware that one proof is given in [Nielsen & Chuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information), and it is pitched at approximately the level I have in mind, but I would prefer a more streamlined source, if one exists.

Maybe these two requirements are contradictory. More streamlined sources, including [Deutsch's](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1989.0099) and [Divincenzo's](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9407022) original papers, may necessarily assume a familiarity with quantum mechanics and computing theory that make them uninviting for undergraduates. But if anyone knows of any sources that start from a place similar to [Nielsen & Chuang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Computation_and_Quantum_Information) but focus on universal quantum gate sets, I would be very interested. Sources may include textbooks, articles, and online notes.

It would be especially nice if a source related the result to geometric or Lie-theoretic properties of $SU(n)$, but that is absolutely not a necessity.

Comment: I recommend S.M. Barnett, *Quantum Information*. Imho: that subject requires only familiarity with $\mathbb C^2$ and its tensor products and can be viewed as a branch of linear algebra. This does not make it trivial though but there is no other physical theory that requires less mathematical prerequisites. Ideal for undergraduates.

Comment: The Lie theory of $SU(2)$ you can learn from P. Woit, *Quantum Theory Groups and Representations.* I think for both books there exist free preprints in the internet.

Comment: [This](https://qiskit.org/) may not be as comprehensive as an undergraduate course but it may be useful. It's a software toolkit but there are learning resources associated with it.

Comment: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com

Comment: Now that the semester is over I can follow up: I think Nielsen and Chuang is the ideal reference for what I was asking, but due to my student's particular interests we went with Woit and had a bit of a different focus than I anticipated—so thank you to @KurtG. for the recommendation. And I can definitely see a different student preferring to focus on learning by doing with Qiskit